# Import single user from sql file

Tags: sql, joomla3.0

From the Joomla database I exported the entire nligu_users table with the users. Now I would like to copy only some of them to a new database. Can you tell me how to do it?

Thank you for your help
Igor

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT username FROM oldtable
WHERE username in ('name1','name2','name3')
```

Something like that?